# how to set onclicklistener for many programatically added views where are buttons

Tags: java, android-studio, tableview, onclicklistener

i have table layout in which is as rows added diferent view (in which are buttons another table views and...) multiple times based on data which i input...
but each row should be movable or deletable by buttons in that view.

so my question is: how can I reach these buttons and set on them onclick listeners which will know where this click came from for me to be able to do something with that row based on button from anodher xml

that table what i tallking about looks like this:

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/main_orders_scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/middle"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/header"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/middle"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" >
        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_orders_table"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/main_orders_row"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <include
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:id="@+id/myid1"
                    layout="@layout/order" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/main_orders_rows"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

and it including another view where are buttons which are supposed to do something with that row

or is it cleaner to do this one diferently ?

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.order_X_btn);
    orderTable = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_orders_table);
    order = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.main_orders_rows);
    //final ViewGroup orders = (ViewGroup) orderTable;
    plus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.plus);
    plus.setOnClickListener(this);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    //orderTable.addView(order);

}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.order_X_btn:
            deleteOrder(v);
            break;
        case R.id.plus:
            addOrder();
            break;
    }
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

private void addOrder() {
    last++;
    final View extend = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.order,null);
    extend.setTag(orderTable.getChildAt(last));
    button.setTag(extend);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
    //deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener);
    orderTable.addView(extend);

}

private void deleteOrder(View v) {
    last--;
    //final View extend = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.order,null);
    orderTable.removeView(v);

}
```

Comment: How do you add those views? With `ViewGroup` you can iterate over sub views using `getChildCount ()` and `getChildAt()` and find your buttons. `View` class also has a few method  that might be handy: `findViewsWithText()`, `findViewWithTag()`.

Comment: i allready saw and tryed that getChildAt() method but like that i can find that button but the main problem is that i do not know how could i define on click listener parent to it that is my problem to define theese onclick listeners unlimited times and know which onclick listener is part of that row

Comment: when you create a new view programatically you assign tags to views by using `setTag(object)`. The tag can be anything, let's you created a new row, find delete button there, set the row (which is parent view) as a tag to the delete button, and then set onClickListener - `deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener ... );` and inside `onClick(View v)` method you can declare a new method `removeRow(View v)` where you can get the tag from `v` which is row and remove it.

Comment: i am sory but still can not set any onclick listener to button in another view which is added to table... i edited my question and added simple testing class. mabie i thinking about it diferently and looks like a idiot but i rly do not know how to find that button multiple times and set for them some id or tag to be able to set onclick listeners for them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: the code below is untested, just giving you a hint.
Assuming you have some sort of plus button to add a new row and every single row has its own delete button.

On create method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    //no idea what is order_X_btn, but I assume that's delete row button
    // if so then you don't need it here 
    //button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.order_X_btn);
    orderTable = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_orders_table);
    order = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.main_orders_rows);
    //final ViewGroup orders = (ViewGroup) orderTable;
    plus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.plus);
    plus.setOnClickListener(this);
    //this is not needed here either
    //button.setOnClickListener(this);
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    //orderTable.addView(order);

}
```

Then onClick:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.plus:
            addOrder();
            break;
    }
}
```

Add order:

```
private void addOrder() {
    last++;
    final View extend = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.order,null);
    extend.setTag(orderTable.getChildAt(last));
    Button deleteButton = (Button) extend.findViewById(R.id.order_X_btn);
    deleteButton.setTag(extend);
    // set anonymous on click listener which triggers deleteOrder method
    deleteButton.setOnClickListener(v -> deleteOrder(v));
    orderTable.addView(extend);

}
```

Delete order:

```
private void deleteOrder(View v) {
    last--;
    
    orderTable.removeView((View) v.getTag());

}
```

There might be some mistakes as I don't have IDE atm, but I hope you got the idea.

Comment: thanks a lot this saved me. tryed to done it many hours... and it is this easy thanks